# PHPMYADMIN: mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, mbstring

Trying to get the phpmyadmin up and running. I installed the myadmin, but keep getting the "mbstring extension is missing" error. Followed some of the advise that was given in the other answers, still having the same issue. (Uncommented the mbstring.dll, added full path to the extension_dir in the php.ini-development and php.ini-production. I do not have a php.ini file other than these two. I tried the phpinfo() function, but it showed me some generic path (c:\windows) without actually showing me which file is being used as the actual .ini

Comment: Probably need more information to be able to answer.

Comment: using windows 8, apache 2.4, PHP 5.6. Let me know what else you are looking for

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making your changes?

Comment: yes, I solved it just an hour ago. Changed the name of the php.ini-production to php.ini and restarted the server (along with all other changes mentioned in question). It worked!